# Bootstrap <a> list-group-item format breaks when including col-xx-x spans

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[This example](http://www.bootply.com/SSIHN1ga8O) illustrates the problem I'm having.  Example 1 and 2, are perfect.  No issues.  In example 3, the format falls apart and I'm not sure why.  How can I make Example 3 look like the other examples, but allow me to grid out the list-group-item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution would be to add the `clearfix` class to the `list-group-item` elements because their children elements are floated. I would recommend the alternative solution below, though. This solution doesn't produce the desired results due to the fact that the columns' padding isn't displaced.

[**Updated Example**](http://www.bootply.com/fFeNLo1e4w)

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="" class="list-group-item clearfix">
      <span class="col-md-6">One Item</span>
      <span class="col-md-6">OneB Item</span>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="list-group-item clearfix">
      <span class="col-md-6">Two Item</span>
      <span class="col-md-6">TwoB Item</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could also just wrap the column elements with the `.row` class, which has a built in clearfix. This is probably the better solution given that the rows displace the padding with `margin-right: -15px`/`margin-left: -15px`.

[In HTML5 it's fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct) to have a `div` element within an anchor element.

[**Updated Example**](http://www.bootply.com/lFAtgcyIWx)

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="" class="list-group-item">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="col-md-6">One Item</span>
      <span class="col-md-6">OneB Item</span>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="list-group-item">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="col-md-6">Two Item</span>
      <span class="col-md-6">TwoB Item</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this valid HTML? `a` nested in `ul`?

Comment: @JustinSkiles Good point. No, it's not valid. I updated it. `ol`/`ul` elements can only contain `li` elements. I should have caught that when I answered this question, but I was just basing it off of the OPs HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem relies on really bad coding practices, hence you had a good result only by luck, but you can't reproduce it because.... it's bad from the start.

Just change your HTML in sample 3 like this:

```
<!-- Example 3 -->
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="row list-group-item"><span class="col-md-6">One Item</span><span class="col-md-6">OneB Item</span></li>
  <li class="row list-group-item"><span class="col-md-6">Two Item</span><span class="col-md-6">TwoB Item</span></li>
</ul>
```

Now you'll see how I use ROW CLASS which is needed for Bootstrap.... rows. But most important, I use the `li` element inside `ul` element, which is like 99% of the solution to your issue. Basically, just use HTML as intended and it will work most of the times. Also, get used to test in [Validator](http://validator.w3.org), you'll get fast answers at a glimpse without having to wait here for an answer.

**EDIT:** Needless to say you must change your other samples that work by luck